# C++: function with vector of any derived class on input

Tags: c++, class, parameters, vector

Let's have the following simple function (the body of my function is more complicated but  for the sake of simplicity):

```
unsigned VctSize(const vector< Base_class > vct) {
  return vct.size()
}
```

How can I make the function accept vectors of derived classes of Base_class on input? 
And can I make the function accept vectors of any type?

In other words, I would like to a write a single function that takes vector of any derived class of Base_class and uses only vector manipulation (no members or member functions of the derived classes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will accept vectors of any type

```
template <class T>
unsigned VecSize(const vector<T>& vct)
{
    return vct.size();
}
```

In order to accept only vectors of derived classes, you can use [boost::enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html)

```
template<class T>
typename enable_if<is_base_and_derived<BaseClass, T>, unsigned>::type 
VecSize(const vector<T>& vct)
{
   return vct.size();
}
```

Comment: And you can use type traits with a static assert to limit them.

Comment: @Cat: I suggested a solution with enable_if... although I am not sure with the syntax

Comment: @OP: Note that this is entirely independent of any base/derived hierarchy. If that was relevant in any way to you, please update the question to include details.

Comment: Thanks - it works perfectly! And the enable_if syntax is correct now too (it took me a while to get it right with the original answer). Kerrek: The base/derive hierarchy does not play a role for me.